# Can I make my Mini-Marios stop walking?

Tags: mario-vs-dk-3

I am playing Mario vs Donkey Kong: Minis March Again, and I missed a few of the tutorial screens, so I just might have missed this information.

In the previous game, you could stop your Minis by tapping them, and they would hold still. I tried that in this game, and the Mini kept walking, which meant that I lost the level (the timer ran out before the second Mini reached the door).

Is there a way to make the Mini stop walking momentarily so the other one can catch up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem like this is [possible anymore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_vs._Donkey_Kong:_Minis_March_Again!):

> [N]one of the minis may be stopped or turned directly by the player. Only items and obstacles can be used to control their direction.

Comment: Oh, that is just annoying! :(